# Send Local SMS using mobile apps while apps received HTTP request

Tags: android, mobile, smsmanager, smpp

I have a question in my mind and the possibility of this.
Is it possible to make a mobile apps that will receive HTTP or SMPP request and read the recipient number and message from that HTTP/smpp request and send SMS to recipient number with that message.
Is it possible or its actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, SMPP protocol is used by a backend application to connect to an SMSC(inside a network operator or one of its 3rd parties) to send/receive SMS.

Maybe you could send the request from the mobile app to a backend service that would use smpp/http to deliver the SMS for you?